# SQL - Convert VARCHAR to Decimal

Tags: sql, select, decimal

I have this Column (varchar(100),null) with this type of values: USTX00001099.

The last four characters of this value means $10.99

How can I convert/extract the 10.99 in a Select function?

Comment: which rdbms do you use?

Comment: Is it alway last 4 characters?

Comment: Are the first 4 characters always 'USTX' followed by a number with an implied decimal position ?

Comment: RDBMS - MS SQL Server. The first 4 characters are always TEXT (USTX,USCA, etc.meaning US - United States and TX - Texas) and after that it can be any number but most of the time the value is below 100.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm new at this. I'm looking at the values and it isn't always the same number of characters. But what I'm trying to do is to use the RIGHT function and select the last 4 characters and divide by 100. But when I have this value: 0499 the new value will come as 4 and not 4.99

I'm using this select: RIGHT(COLUMN,4) /100

Answer (score 0):

It could be this:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(col, 4)) / 100. FROM table
```

Comment: Sorry BWS, I'm new at this. I'm looking at the values and it isn't always the same number of characters. But what I'm trying to do is to use the RIGHT function and select the last 4 characters and divide by 100. But when I have this value: 0499 the new value will come as 4 and not 4.99 I'm using this select: RIGHT(COLUMN,4) /100

Answer (score 0):

Two ways come to mind. **First**, you can select he last 4 digits, convert it to a numeric type, and then divide by 4.

```
select cast(right(name,4) as float) / 100
```

if you need to enforce a currency formatting, you could use another cast like

```
select cast(cast(right(name,4) as float) / 100 as numeric(8,2))
```

The **second** way, which I think is better, is to format the string before you cast it. Something like

```
select cast(SUBSTRING(name,len(name)-3,2) + '.' + RIGHT(name,2) as numeric(8,2))
```

This should answer your current question. However, you're going to run into problems trying to do this for items that cost hundreds or thousands of dollars.